# How do you vertically align the body tag of an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that is horizontally centered but is rather short - it only takes up half the vertical page.  I want it to be centered.  How can I center the  tag vertically?  I cannot have a static height, so that is not an option.  if CSS is not powerful enough, can I use Javascript to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Comment: Try [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+vertical+align+body) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind adding non-semantic markup, you can do this:

**html:**

```
<div class="pusher"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.pusher {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50%;
}
.center {
    background: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jsqqk/

---

If you do care about semantic markup, and have to support older browsers, then you'll have to resort to JavaScript for this. Here's one solution using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
var $window = $(window),
    $container = $('#container');

$window.resize(function(){
    $container.css('margin-top',
        Math.max(($window.height() / 2) - ($container.height() / 2), 0)
    );
}).resize();
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dw3rc/

Comment: I do care about semantec markup...and i had a feeling i would have to use something like JS.  How do i do this with javascript???

Comment: @alecwhardy: I've updated my answer to include a javascript solution for semantic markup.

Answer (score 4):

Two primary ways, neither of which is especially perfect, but widely used:

1) if your content really is a fixed, known height, then you CSS position it with

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: here, set a pixel value that's equal to: -1 * (content height / 2)
```

2) If you don't care if it works the same way in IE7 and below, set CSS as follows:

```
html { display: table; }
body { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've often done this with setting height:50% and padding-top:25% but that's not always suitable.

This page identifies a different technique that might work:

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html