# Label vertical alignment in middle of page does not work

Tags: css

Here is my fiddle to put text at vertical middle of the page.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/5a5WG/)

HTML:

```
<label class="label"> Should be in middle </label>
```

CSS:

```
.label{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but it does not put it in middle

Comment: In the middle of what? Vertical alignment only works on multiple elements.

Comment: Your CSS will align the *content* of the `.label` in the middle of the element. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qk5Dq/): the text is middle-aligned within the red-bordered-box.

Comment: @Jeroen: I want to align text in middle of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gS8k8/1/)**

**The HTML Code:**

```
<label class="label"> Should be in middle </label>
```

**The CSS Code:**

```
    .label{
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:150px;
    line-height:150px;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

***PS:** height and line-height values should be same for it to work. You can put any values, but for illustrative purposes, I have used 150px*

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5a5WG/2/)**

**css**

```
div{
    background-color:red;
    display: table; vertical-align: middle;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
label{
display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
.label{
text-align:center;
margin:0px auto;
display:block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:0;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

check this fiddle

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri/5a5WG/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Your label is the `only-child` in body. Body height is setting by label height, so you code trying to set your text in the middle of one-line text. And it do it and works fine.

If you want to set in the middle one-line text will be better to use `line-height` css property:

```
<div style="height: 30px;line-height: 30px;">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's hard to say from just this little piece of code. But I think the Problem is, that if you want the label to be vertically aligned, you have to set the class to the element containing your label. Like this i.e.:

```
    <div class="label">
        <label>Middle</label>
    </div>
```

css:

```
    .label
    {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. As of w3schools([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)), the vertical-align is assigned to the element which is supposed to be aligned. So sorry for that false information. But you could try this:
[Another SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142252/how-do-you-vertically-align-the-body-tag-of-an-html-document)